# Java: Simple issue with Interfaces and Generics

Tags: java, generics, interface, comparable

I made an interface to work with JGraphT. My intended use is like `Comparable`, in that implementing `Comparable` allows objects to be used with certain data structures. Simiarly, I have a JGraphT function that I want to work with anything that is `Distanceable`.

```
public interface Distanceable<E> {

    /**
     * A representation of the distance between these two objects.
     * If the distance between a0 and a1 is undefined, <code>a0.hasEdge(a1)</code> should return false;
     * @param o
     * @return
     */
    public int distance(E o);

    /**
     * Are these two objects connected?
     * @param o
     * @return True if the two objects are connected in some way, false if their distance is undefined
     */
    public boolean hasEdge(E o);
}
```

Here is my JGraphT function in JGraphtUtilities. It's not defined for `Animal`, but for `Distanceable`:

```
public static <E extends Distanceable> WeightedGraph<E, DefaultWeightedEdge> graphOfDistances(Set<E> nodes) {
    WeightedGraph<E, DefaultWeightedEdge> g = new SimpleWeightedGraph<E, DefaultWeightedEdge>(DefaultWeightedEdge.class);

    for (E a : nodes) {
        g.addVertex(a);
    }

    for (E a : nodes) {
        for (E a1 : nodes) {
            if (a.hasEdge(a1)) {
                g.addEdge(a, a1);
                g.setEdgeWeight(g.getEdge(a, a1), a.distance(a1));
            }
        }
    }

    return g;
}
```

But it doesn't work. The compiler produces an error on this line in another class that calls this method:

```
WeightedGraph<Animal, DefaultWeightedEdge> graphOfAnimals = JGraphtUtilities.graphOfAnimals(zoo);
```

The error is:

```
The method graphOfAnimals(Set<Animal>) is undefined for the type JGraphtUtilities
```

However,

```
public class Animal implements Distanceable<Animal> {
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Another issue: The compiler gives this warning:

```
Distanceable is a raw type. References to generic type Distanceable<E> should be parameterized.
```

What type do I want to give it, if I want this function to work with all `Distanceable` objects?

Comment: Can you show us JGraphtUtilitie as well. Does it have the method graphOfAnimals(Set<Animal>)?

Comment: The method you have included is called graphOfDistances(Set<E> nodes) not graphOfAnimals(Set<Animal>). Are you expecting the compiler to guess what method you actually wanted to call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The method `graphOfAnimals(Set<Animal>)`
>   is undefined for the type
>   JGraphtUtilities

The method you're displaying in your code sample is `graphOfDistances`.
The problem is with the method `graphOfAnimals`. So...

Do you have a `graphOfAnimals` method that takes a `Set<Animal>` in the  `JGraphtUtilities` class?

Comment: now, but there is a method that takes `Set<Distanceable>`, as shown above.

Comment: @Rosarch: see my edit, if there is such a method you didn't display it.

Comment: ok - another issue - the compiler wants a type parameter for Distanceable in graphOfDistances(). What do I give it?